# why SSL certificate is needed after SSL handshake in same session?

Tags: ssl, https, browser, security, sslhandshakeexception

My question is totally based on Https connections.
Scenario is as : 
Suppose I m connecting to https://www.example.com and after accepting SSL Certificate, I login to the same site and a session gets eshtablished. Then I delete certificate from the Browser and try to browse the same site further and then my browser asks for Acceptance of the certificate for same site. Why so?

As far as I know After SSL handshake when a Secret Key gets generated that key is used for all encryption for that session. I don't think there is any need of Certificate after establishing  session with the server. So why my browser is asking for the certificate in between the established session.

Comment: Considering the reason for removing a trusted cert is often that you no longer trust it, it would make sense to invalidate the sessions that have been started using that cert, even if they're currently active.

Comment: but then why session remains same as session id is same after re-accepting the SSL certificate?

Comment: Not sure. Why not. It's a trust issue from the client point of view. Your browser seems to be doing sensible here.

Comment: As of my findings and @Bruno's suggestions, When i remove trust certificate in between established session, Browser instantly invalidates sessions which are dependent on that removed certificate. So it then asks again for SSL certificate trust Acceptance. I think that's pretty logical.